# SSH to home ubuntu, from different network

Tags: networking, ssh, port-forwarding

I have ubuntu 16.04 laptop, And I want to ssh it from a different network. my router is tp-link AC750. I enabled port forwarding, as in the image [image]

I found my public ip address using google and tried to login remotely, but not working. How can I troubleshoot this?

I modified to port 2222. now getting the following error while trying to connect:

```
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/mobaxterm/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/mobaxterm/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/mobaxterm/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/mobaxterm/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/mobaxterm/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/mobaxterm/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/mobaxterm/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/mobaxterm/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.1
ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
```

Comment: When firing up ssh, use `-v` flag for verbose output. You can then clearly see what exactly went wrong.

Comment: Might be a silly question but: do you have an `sshd` (like `openssh-server`) running on your laptop? I ask because it is not installed by default.

Comment: try with another port on external, many routers don't forward external 22 (also 80, 443). try with eg 2222 forward to 22 on your computer and you MUST test it outside your router network, you can't test it from internal. of course like @PerlDuck said, check if your destination is listening on port 22 from all networks `netstat -anutp grep :22` to check.

Comment: @PerlDuck : I checked. ssh is running.

Comment: @Zina : that moved me a little forward: now I am getting a different error: see edit

Comment: Maybe [Trying to SSH into server and getting key_load_public: No such file or directory error](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/321968/251553) over at U&L is helpful? They suggest to look into the server (=your laptop's) logs.

Comment: yes, as @PerlDuck says, look at both sides, check both sides version and the reason for disconnect